# Get corresponding value from custom list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create custom dropdown list for input element. where I want to enable select one of predefined values for input and also make possible for user to enter his own choice by typing. As you can see in example it works, but if I have  more than one input with dropdown list, it doesn't work.

So the question is how to make possible?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
// dropdown for inputs
var getDataAttr;
$(document).on('focus click', '.input', function(event) {
    $(event.target).next('.dd_items').show();
});
$(document).on('click', '.choose_val', function() {
    $(".input").val($(this).text());
    $('#new-types').fadeOut();
});
$(document).on('focusout', '.input', function () {
    $(event.target).next('.dd_items').hide();
});
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
}

.input {
  width: 220px;
  height: 30px;
}

.dd_items {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  min-width: 220px;
}
.dd_items__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
.dd_items__item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.dd_items__item:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
      <input type="text" id="first" class="input" data-dropdown="#add_new_type">
      <ul id="new-types" style="display: none" class="dd_items">
      <li data-id="1" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Sirst value</li>
      <li data-id="2" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Second value</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <input type="text" id="first" class="input" data-dropdown="#add_new_type">
        <ul id="new-types" style="display: none" class="dd_items">
        <li data-id="1" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Sirst value</li>
        <li data-id="2" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Second value</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

Comment: "but if I have more than one input with dropdown list, it doesn't work". this statement is not clear. What exactly are you tring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So @linkinTED gave you good comment and answer, based on that here is solution with using data-*.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // dropdown for inputs
  var dataName = 'dropdown'; 
  var dataAttr;
  
  $(document).on('focus click', '.input', function() {
    dataAttr = $(this).data(dataName);
    $(document).find(dataAttr).show();;
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.choose_val', function() {
    $('.input[data-dropdown="'+dataAttr+'"]').val($(this).text());
  });
  $(document).on('focusout', '.input', function() {
    $('.new-types').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul style="display: none" class="dd_items new-types" id="add_date">
    <li data-id="1" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Date First value</li>
    <li data-id="2" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Date Second value</li>
    <li data-id="2" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Date Third value</li>
    <li data-id="2" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Date Fourth value</li>
  </ul>
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="text" id="second" class="input" data-dropdown="#add_date">
  
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="text" id="third" class="input" data-dropdown="#add_new_type">
  
</div>

  <ul style="display: none" class="dd_items new-types" id="add_new_type">
    <li data-id="1" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Third First value</li>
    <li data-id="2" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Third Second value</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an `id`, in the case, you rather use classes.

The by travelling up and down the DOM tree, you show and hide the elements  you want...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // dropdown for inputs
  var getDataAttr;
  $(document).on('focus click', '.input', function() {
    $(this).next('.new-types').show();
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.choose_val', function() {
    $(this).parent().prev(".input").val($(this).text());
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
  });
  $(document).on('focusout', '.input', function() {
    $('.new-types').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
}

.input {
  width: 220px;
  height: 30px;
}

.dd_items {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  min-width: 220px;
}

.dd_items__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.dd_items__item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.dd_items__item:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="text" id="first" class="input" data-dropdown="#add_new_type">
  <ul style="display: none" class="dd_items new-types">
    <li data-id="1" class="choose_val dd_items__item">First First value</li>
    <li data-id="2" class="choose_val dd_items__item">First Second value</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="text" id="second" class="input" data-dropdown="#add_new_type">
  <ul style="display: none" class="dd_items new-types">
    <li data-id="1" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Second First value</li>
    <li data-id="2" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Second Second value</li>
    <li data-id="2" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Second Third value</li>
    <li data-id="2" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Second Fourth value</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="text" id="third" class="input" data-dropdown="#add_new_type">
  <ul style="display: none" class="dd_items new-types">
    <li data-id="1" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Third First value</li>
    <li data-id="2" class="choose_val dd_items__item">Third Second value</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for. I have one question related to this. How this can be done if HTML structure is different? For example if those drop downs are not right below their corresponding inputs?

Comment: Sure, there are multiple solutions, 1) with [traversing](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) you can look up and down the DOM tree to find the matching element or 2) use the same class or a custom `data-*` attribute to find the other elements.  A specific answer can only be given with a specific example.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're targeting generic elements rather than specific ones.

In the second event listener you are targeting `'.input'` but if you duplicate this, there will be several `'.input'` available in the DOM.

You should use something like `$(this).closest('.input')` instead.